# Need help in regex pattern which excludes special character in android

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression which restrict the user for accepting special character in android.

I have tried this:

```
!phoneNumber.matches("[/,'*:<>!~@#$%^&()+=?()\"|!\[#$-]")
```

but it always return `true` regardless of whether the phone number contains special character or not.

Comment: You "want"?I will not describe here my wants.What have you tried?

Comment: Define special character.

Comment: I have tried this !phoneNumber.matches("[/,'*:<>!~@#$%^&()+=?()\"|!\\[#$-]")     but it always return true either phonenumber contains apecial character or not.

Comment: @Rohit Jain : special character like !~`@#$%^&*()'

Comment: @nitintyagi.. Ok. And what about - `=, /, \, _, +`??

Comment: @nitintyagi, please post that regex and the code that uses it in your question.

Comment: define 'special character'

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `[/,'*:<>!~@#$%^&()+=?()\"|!\[#$-]` matches any of the listed character occuring once and so is its negation. Thus `!phoneNumber.matches("[/,'*:<>!~@#$%^&()+=?()\"|!\[#$-]")` evaluates to true whether it is **a** or **aa** or **a!** as **aa** and **a!** are not **one** of the characters specified. Only case evaluating to false will be **a single occurrence of any of these characters**.

You have to accept only characters other than these. For this you should use a `^` following the character class opening bracket (`[`) and add a `+` following the closing bracket. This regex matches any one or more characters other than the listed ones.

Required regex will be `"[^/,'*:<>!~@#$%^&()+=?()\"|!\\[#$-]+"` which matches patterns with one or more characters other than these.

**Note:** Your implementation seems to be in java. This regex works in **java**.

**Another thing :** Why have you added `\"` instead of `"`? If it is to escape `"` inside string, you can't give just `\[` but requires `\\[` I think.

Comment: @dan1111 OP's implementation seems to be in java. I don't know any other language with `matches` function with regex as parameter and in Java this works without anchoring.

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be matching a phone number (and a very restricted definition of a phone number at that), I suggest using a positive rather than a negative test:

```
phoneNumber.matches("[\\d\\s]+")
```

This will return true if the field contains only numbers and spaces (normally I would allow other characters, at least `()-+`, in a phone number, but you have excluded those as special characters, so I stayed consistent with that).

This is much simpler and will exclude all invalid characters from the field.

You may want to go beyond that and make sure it is a valid phone number format, as well.  That would depend on what type of phone numbers you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my regex variant of a special character validator:

```
String regExp = "^[^<>{}\"/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*\\]\\\\()\\[¿§«»ω⊙¤°℃℉€¥£¢¡®©0-9_+]*$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
return matcher.matches();
```

(Java code)